# How can I draw chart between 2 categories (strings) using recharts library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, bar-chart, recharts

I want to draw a BarChart using recharts library but the quantities on both axis are strings/variables e.g.

```
[
{y: 'medium', x:'P'},
{y: 'high', x:'Y'},
{y: 'low', x:'SS'},
{y: 'medium', x:'DD'},
{y: 'very high', x:'NN'},
]
```

The height of bars corresponds to the relevant value on y axis, you can see example in attached jpg, by default recharts doesn't support strings/variables on both axis as library determines height based on some numerical value
How can I achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all available y values you can convert them to number values

I wrote small example with conversion, custom colors and labels

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-rbe56s?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Worked like charms! Thanks @Sergey :D